# how to access bss section in assembly

Tags: assembly, x86-64

I'm trying to write/read to/from the bss section, and I'm not sure why it always says the there's undefined reference to main? this is my code: I just wanted to understand how to access to the bss section, that's all.

```
.global _start

.bss
.lcomm data, 8

.text
_start:
    movq $5, data
```

this is the error:

```
Build log:
[06:27:57] Build started...
[06:27:58] Warning! Errors have occurred in the build:
/tmp/SASM/program.asm: Assembler messages:
/tmp/SASM/program.asm: Warning: end of file not at end of a line; newline inserted
/tmp/SASM/program.o: In function `_start':
(.text+0x0): multiple definition of `_start'
/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/7/../../../x86_64-linux-gnu/crt1.o:(.text+0x0): first defined here
/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/7/../../../x86_64-linux-gnu/crt1.o: In function `_start':
(.text+0x20): undefined reference to `main'
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
```

Comment: This is unrelated to your `.bss`. It says undefined reference to `main` because you used `gcc` to link and by default that wants a C style program where the entry point is `main` and not `_start`. So rename that. PS: `.lcomm` switches to `.bss` by itself, you don't need to write it out explicitly.

Comment: PPS: you know your program has no end and will crash, right? If you switch to `main` you might want to add a `ret` at the end.

Comment: Do not post pictures of text please!  I have downvoted your question and will retract my downvote once you replace the picture with an error message as text.

Comment: @fuz sorry! I thought it would be ok just to paste the trace.I won't repeat that again.

Comment: For an explanation of why it's a problem and why people care about this, see https://idownvotedbecau.se/imageofanexception/.  Images don't get indexed by search engines, and are opaque to blind users using screen readers.  And some corporate firewalls block imgur.

Comment: @PeterCordes thank you, I will read that. thank you everyone for your advises! I've managed to make it work